# Проблема с запуском локального сервера после клонирования проекта на другой компьютер

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, github, localhost

Решил впервые поработать удаленно дома над своим проектом на node.js, в котором установлены некоторые модули. Ранее я проект залил на гитхаб, теперь, я загрузил его на свой домашний компьютер с помощью *Гитхаб Декстоп*. После открытия файла прописал в терминале *npm i*. Код работает с папками на компьютере, поэтому единственное что изменил в коде, так это путь до файлов. Но появилось странное подчеркивание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда поставились пакеты, то я попытался поднять сервер с помощью node "имя серверного файла", на что терминал выдал вот такую ошибку:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Рабочие проекты\serverTest_addFiles>node scriptServer
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Рабочие проекты\serverTest_addFiles\scriptServer.js:11
const directory="C:\\Users\user\\Desktop\\Рабочие проекты\\serverTest_addFiles\\experimentFolder";
                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Ну и по ссылке http://localhost:3000/ ничего не появилось соответственно.

Comment: Между users и user добавьте еще 1 слэш

Comment: Все верно, был невнимательным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы там везде два \ ставите, а в месте ошибки одну \

Comment: Спасибо большое, невнимателен